# Is there a way to use map tiles exported from openstreetmap in OSRM server?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I am trying to host OSRM server locally only for 1 city, Is it possible to get the .pbf file for the specific city (Since osrm server requires tiles in that format)? if Possible how?
Or is there any alternative?

I already hosted osrm server for Berlin city using the documentation provided
https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Running-OSRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bbbike.org allows you to create pbf files for custom shapes via their [online tool](https://extract.bbbike.org/). Also, they have some ready-made pbf extracts for some cities [here](https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at OSM [country and area extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) to check whether there is a PBF file for your city.

If not, download a larger extract containing your city and [split it into a smaller geographic region](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions), for example using [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) with the `extract` argument.